# Reset password link on Django website not working in production

Tags: python, django

I have a django website. It has sign up and login functionality for users. It's currently hosted on pythonanywhere. I am using the gmail smtp server to send mails from the contact form and for reset password. But the reset link sent in the email is not working. When I'm running the localhost, the link works but not when hosted on pythonanywhere. What could be wrong? Here is my urls.py file's code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTQqg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uHry.png)

Comment: hi @zin-minhtun please could you add the login template code?  If possible add also the link you receive and errors description when you click on it

Comment: edited my post... thanks

Comment: I think your problem has been resolved as in that  link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421887/django-email-with-smtp-gmail-smtpauthenticationerror-534-application-specific-pa  try to achieve instructions of answer provided there and give us the feedback.