# Sending mail now for testing after disabling the less secure app setting in gmail

Tags: django, email, django-models, django-rest-framework, localhost

I was trying to send mail to test one of my Django Rest Framework projects. I know I have to turn on the "Less Secure Apps Permission" for Gmail to receive the mail from the localhost. But Google disabled that setting from June 30.

I've tried using the app passwords from gmail but it's not working as well. Now how I can be able to send emails from localhost?

I'm getting this error:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django email with smtp.gmail SMTPAuthenticationError 534 Application-specific password required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421887/django-email-with-smtp-gmail-smtpauthenticationerror-534-application-specific-pa)

Comment: @SumitSChawla Thanks but no it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

The existing advice is out of date. Security policy has changed. For more information, see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72794822/13842923).

Comment: thanks for this. I shall use a different SMTP server.