# Set Django send_mail backend host with Gmail

Tags: django, smtp-auth

I have been trying search many files to set send_mail backend with Gmail host. Here is my settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myemail'
```

It doesn't work...I find someone mentioned to set Gmail Account with "less secure app". So I tried, but it didn't work. On google website, it says:"To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password." (refer to: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en).

Regardless of all, I still tried to use python3 manage.py shell, and got the error:
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials jj4-20020a170903048400b0016a2b68823esm9889669plb.141 - gsmtp')

Could anyone help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: That's a great resource. Sounds like it's not allowed anymore. Sounds like there's a way to possibly allow it with the "less secure app access" is enabled, somehow in the admin if you really want (maybe -- they don't explicitly say it's toggle-able). I recommend just not using gmail for this, use an email send provider... Sendgrid, SES etc. I agree w/ Google that insecure access is dangerous for the web.

Comment: I got similar issue fixed by setting multi factor authentication and then creating app in google. That app password is then used in django as gmail password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar experience. When I tested the software, I got the error you mentioned. It made me very nervous.

The temporary solution was to change the account password. Then for some time, I was able to test again using gmail. Unfortunately, but after a short time, the access was blocked.

I have not found a solution and the previous settings are not available. It's a shame that the service makes everything difficult. You can try free SMTP alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Effective May 30 2022, Google won't let an app login to Gmail with the usual account password. See: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

To work around this you must use a Google "App Password". At myaccount.google.com go to Security, turn on 2FA, then create an App Password.

Use the App Password in place of the account password and it will work.

Comment: Thank you, and what have I use as an app name? My actual project name, or my email, or just localhost, or something else?

Comment: @kokserek I don't remember, but I don't think it matters.

Comment: Yes, I found some examples. It doesn't matter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best answer here is from nerdfever.com.  I just want to clarify it and elaborate...

First - Go to myaccount.google.com, perform a search for 'App Passwords'.  Click the link, 'select app', give it a name (I named mine the name of my Django Project), click 'Generate' and it will provide you with your App Password. Copy it and keep it somewhere safe.

Next - Open your settings.py in your Django project.  You should already have populated the file with your smtp gmail settings.  Paste your App Password:   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'app password here'.  Now, if your views.py code is correct, you should be able to send your emails from your Contact form.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).