# How to salve this error SMTPAuthenticationError at /auth/users/

Tags: django

I am trying to send email from backend to other but I face to this error

(534, b'5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at\n5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor f25-20020a05651c03d900b00295a5aa9d05sm1136834ljp.120 - gsmtp')

Comment: Where is the email sending code and SMTP Configuration?

Comment: EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

Comment: Add all the values and code in post by edit your question.

Comment: I hope this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421887/django-email-with-smtp-gmail-smtpauthenticationerror-534-application-specific-pa